# Excel error: thick lines appear after changing cells, disappear when screen refreshed

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I think it is more of some bugs of excel rather than anything, and I have no idea what I did that made it behaves like this. It was normal until recently.

The problem is that now whenever I change the content of a cell, black borders appear around it or around the row of it. These black borders are not like  permanent changes that are made to the cells. They appear right after I change the cell, and when I do anything that refreshes the Excel window (such as scroll to the right and then scroll back left, or switch to another application and then switch back) they disappear, which seems to me like some kind of memory problem. However, even when I cancel all excel applications or even restart my computer, it still happens the next time I turn on excel.

It would be great if somebody can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Someone posted me an answer as an edit to my question. Though I cannot try it right now, I want to post it here in case it may be the fix to my problem and others having the same problem can have a look at it.

**Solution:**

### https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fixes-or-workarounds-for-recent-issues-in-Excel-for-Windows-49d932ce-0240-49cf-94df-1587d9d97093

Dark borders around rows and cells appear when entering text in Excel 2016 after Sept 12, 2017 update (KB4011050) [FIXED]